# To convert .tiff to .jpg in Next.js (react)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js

I tried to convert a .tiff to .jpg using jimp, but
However, jimp uses many libraries that are not available in the browser, such as `fs, path, stream, zlib` and so on.

Is there a good way to convert .tiff to .jpg in Next.js?

Comment: Do you have to convert the image on the client-side? Could you not have it done in an API route instead, where you can use Node.js APIs (`fs`, `path`, etc)?

Comment: I remembered that and responded with an api route! Thanks.